# Sklearn set_config is erroring

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am facing an issue where the sklearn set_config is failing.
I am using Google Colab and also it is failing on Jupyter Notebook as well.
Even the code when copied from https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/release_highlights/plot_release_highlights_0_23_0.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-release-highlights-plot-release-highlights-0-23-0-py also failing with same error.

```
from sklearn import set_config
set_config(display='diagram')
```

Error: TypeError: set_config() got an unexpected keyword argument 'display'

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Comment: Is the sklearn version is >0.23.0 in colab?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i was using older version. After upgrade and restart runtime, now i am able to use set_config() and its working as expected.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to upgrade scikit-learn on colab, its version is `'v0.22.2.post1'`, while `display` parameter in `set_config()` function was introduced in `v0.23`.

```
!pip install --upgrade scikit-learn
```

Then, restart the runtime, `display` should work now.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately i was using older version. After upgrade and restart runtime, now i am able to use set_config() and its working as expected.

Comment: It worked after I upgrade the package and restarted the kernel.  Thank you!